# Python upload Data in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, for-loop, upload

I'm uploading data from a JSON file in MongoDB but I want to take each 5 datapoints into 1 field in mongo and I'm using this loop:

```
document = {}

for key, data_point in zip(fields, data[:5]):
    for sub_key, value in data_point.items():
        document[f"{key}_{sub_key}"] = value

# Insert Data
collection.insert_one(document)
```

It works for me on getting 5 datapoints into 1 Mongo field but it only uploads the first 5 and doesn't continue looping to get all 3170 fields that I have which should create 634 fields in Mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are taking first 5 items. You should iterate through every 5 items. Here example:

```
chunks = [data[x:x+5] for x in range(0, len(data), 5)]
for chunk in chunks:
    document = {}
    for i, data_point in enumerate(chunk):
        for sub_key, value in data_point.items():
            # Create new field key based on the index of the chunk and the sub_key
            document[f"{i}_{sub_key}"] = value
    # Insert Data
    collection.insert_one(document)
```

Comment: @Zzz does it make sence?

Comment: @ Baktybek Baiserkeev Yes it totally worked. Thank you so much on your help.